# Android use stock material design buttons

Tags: android, material-design

I'm working on an android app for a hackathon and I'd like to have a floating action button (round with a plus). So there's tons of material design documentation on how to design them, but I just want to use the stock one, like in the Alarm app.

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="25dp" android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/basketButton"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"/>
```

all the stock drawables in the android namespace look like from the 1950s. Where can I find the modern ones?

Or do I seriously have to copy design them myself?

Comment: you mean the material drawables? you can find them here officially from google: https://material.io/icons/

Comment: https://material.io/icons/

Comment: But I still have to download them and add them to my project and  create a custom round button etc. etc.? No way to simply reference @android:drawable/ic_done or something?

Comment: no, not as far as i know. I think that is intended by google so you have full control over how the icons look

Comment: @stamanuel you can add the drawables to your project from within Android-studio, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the material-icons to your project from within Android studio.
You can add them as vector-files, or just as plain Drawables.
You have to right-click on your res-folder, and select new-> vector asset or new -> image asset if you want to add them as drawables. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html) and [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio.html)

Edit: You don't have to create a custom round button. You can just use the FloatingActionButton, which can be found in the support-library